# Octomap Self-filtering

Tags: kinect, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using UR5 moveit model with a kinect. I followed this tutorial

http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/perception_configuration.html

to add the kinect like a sensor. I add some parameter to do a self robot filter, but when I launch the robot model (roslaunch ur5_moveit_config demo.launch) I get the next error:

```
[ERROR] [1425487423.826931655]: Transform error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time   1425487423.780933888 but the latest data is at time 1425487423.751322031, when looking up transform from frame   [forearm_link] to frame [camera_rgb_optical_frame]
[ERROR] [1425487423.827004659]: Transform cache was not updated. Self-filtering may fail.
```

Anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks.

This is my yaml file:

```
sensors:
  - sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
    point_cloud_topic: /camera/depth_registered/points
    max_range: 5.0
    point_subsample: 1
    padding_offset: 0.1
    padding_scale: 1.0
    filtered_cloud_topic: filtered_cloud
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204235/octomap-self-filtering/) by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2015-03-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2015-03-05**:
where's the error message?

**Comment by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on 2015-03-05**:
Edited question.

**Comment by [R@m](https://answers.ros.org/users/25832/r@m/) on 2017-05-22**:
Have you rectified it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I faced the same issue while using a depth camera with Mico2 arm. Solved it by following this [thread](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/issues/465).

I had to remove my binary installation of moveit and use a source version to modify the changes. Eventually, the source codes and header files are already modified in their [rep](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/indigo-devel). Additionally, you need to modify your planning_context.launch file and add the wait time as mentioned [here](https://github.com/corot/thorp/commit/eeb5bae5e5af40ea69f475c510409fd2fe164e61).

---

Originally posted by [R@m](https://answers.ros.org/users/25832/r@m/) with karma: 98 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2020-05-08**:
I was facing the same error while working with intel real-sense depth camera and with my 5DOF arm.

Modified below lines to `moveit_config/launch/planning_context.launch` file solves problem as suggested by @R@m,

```
  <group ns="$(arg robot_description)_planning">
    <param name="shape_transform_cache_lookup_wait_time" value="0.1" />
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find thorp_moveit_config)/config/joint_limits.yaml"/>
  </group>
```